# Get all tags on taggable object - no matter context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I use acts-as-taggable-on on a collection of photos. I have a general :tags context and an :objectives context that users use for stuff that is in the photo. In the UI I add both tag contexts into the same box. 
It would be nice if I could get all tags and objectives on one photo in one command, like:

```
photo.gimme_all_tags_no_matter_context #would give me combined list of general tags and objectives.
```

Currently I do this:

```
tags = "#{photo.tags.map{|c| c.name}.join(",")},#{photo.objectives.map{|c| c.name}.join(",")}"
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You table with all tags is

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging
```

To get all tags you do this

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all
```